# automatic count the number of 1-n instance in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two mySql tables in a 1-n relationship. In the first table I need to set a field representing the number of instance of the second table, and keep it updated.
What is the best way to accomplish this? I have to update the counter every time I insert/delete a record in the second table or is there an automatic way to do it?

Comment: `SELECT a.id, COUNT(b.id) FROM a, b WHERE b.fkFromA = a.id GROUP BY a.id`should work for you. But this is done at runtime, so the counting takes time.

Comment: Please check if the runtime query as suggested by @Najzero is not preferred, you might think of creating view with this query and getting data from view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have it as a field in the first table you need to update the counter every time that you insert/delete a record in the second table.

Alternatively, when you need to retrieve the data, you can just query the second table, joining with the first and filtering on the Id from the first table. If you don't need the data every time that you retrieve a record from the first table and if you are inserting/deleting lots from the second table, then this will be the more efficient route.

Comment: ok, so there are no field types or istructions that can rappresent the count and keep it updated. I must calculate the number on every insert/delete nd update it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the run-time query as suggested by @Najzero is not preferred you might think of creating **`View`** with this query and getting data from **`View`**

Also if you need to update the field every-time on insert/delete, you can consider creating **`Trigger`** on INSERT and DELETE operation.